# Microsoft Graph API link to auto create application with correct permissions

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have an app that uses graph API to get some data from Office365 from multiple customers.
At the moment, every time I have a new customer I need to log in as admin on to their azure portal, create the app, add permissions and consent for the permissions.

Is there any way I can generate a link that I send to the customer, they just click it, consent and the application ID's are returned so they can provide us?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate app registration in each customer's tenant, you could have a single app registration, controlled by you in your tenant. Then, each of your customers would grant consent to your app in their tenants, for example by going to an [admin consent URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) that you provide to them.

Comment: Hi Philippe. Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it is possible to do the same thing but have Application permissions assigned on the creates Enterprise App at the customer's tenant? Here's a question I asked that remains unanswered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292198/how-do-i-expose-an-azure-ad-application-api-and-give-it-application-permissions